# firebase export issue in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a file named `firebase.js`.
It contains the following code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "some_random_key",
    authDomain: "some_random_authDomain",
    databaseURL: "some_random_databaseURL",
    projectId: "some_random_projectId",
    storageBucket: "some_random_bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "some_random_Id"
};

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Now I am importing this in my `index.js` React file as below;

```
import firebaseApp from './firebase'
```

This gives me the following error:

```
./src/index.js
13:0-11 "export 'default' (imported as 'firebaseApp') was not found in './firebase'
```

and if I change my import statement to:

```
import {firebaseApp} from './firebase'
```

it's working fine.
I know this is related to javascript but can you please explain me the concept here.

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports) `fireBase` from `firebase.js`. This means that you have to use the curly brace syntax specifying the name of your export.

To export a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export) use

```
export default firebase.initializeApp(config)
// or if you prefer to assign the result to a variable before exporting
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)
export default firebaseApp
```

This allows you to import your default export and call it what you wish, e.g. `import firebaseApp from './firebase'` or `import foo from './firebaseApp`

Comment: if I am using export default firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);                  I am getting the error that firebaseApp is not defined

Comment: oh..ok now I get it, you initialize it and then export it.

Comment: Can we use it like,   export default const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config); ??

Comment: You can't use that syntax for default exports, you can for named exports though. You don't have to assign the value to a variable since you're not using the value other than in the export, that's why `export default firebase.initializeApp(config)` works

Comment: When I'm try to get reference to database firebaseApp.database.child('contacts')   I get following error.TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["default"].database.child')